# Why is my COUNTIF function within excel not working?

Tags: excel, countif

In my excel document I have two sheets. Within the first sheet I am trying to create a function that will return the total number of cells within a column from the other sheet that contain a value of `<= 40`. The following is the formula I have been trying:

```
=COUNTIF(NameofOtherSheetD3:D200, <=40)
```

And I am receiving the standard excel error message, "Not trying to type a formula [...] etc.".

I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
=COUNTIF(NameofOtherSheet!D3:D200, "<=40")
```

When creating the formula, I let Excel prepare the first parameter by moving to the sheet `NameofOtherSheet` and selecting the range. The difference noted between your version and what Excel prepared is there's a ! character at the end of the sheet name.

And for specifying the `<=` condition, it simply needed to be surrounded by quotes.

> ***Edit:***
> Just to address your point of Excel reporting Not trying to type a formula...this is happening because the condition `<=40` isn't surrounded by quotes. As soon as `<=40` is surrounded by quotes, Excel no longer reports  Not trying to type a formula however the formula results in a `#NAME`? error and this is due to the range being specified correctly (missing the ! character after the sheet name)